# DB2 SQL Query not considering spaces in field's data

Tags: sql, db2

The database in my application saves data in table's field with spaces. But when I query the data it's not considering spaces in field's data And gives the all result irrespective the spaces

```
VAT_TABLE.VAR_DATA
------------------
I                   --- 1 space after I
I                   --- 2 space after I
I                   --- 0 space after I
I                   --- 1 space after I
I                   --- 3 space after I
I                   --- 4 space after I
```

When I run this query >>>  `SELECT * FROM VAT_TABLE WHERE VAR_DATA = 'I '`

**The result gives all 6 rows irrespective the spaces after 'I'**

Any Idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 specifically ignores trailing spaces when comparing two strings.

So "I" == "I " == "I         "

If you want to differentiate between "I" and "I  " you need :-

```
WHERE VAR_DATA = 'I' AND LENGTH(VAR_DATA) = 2
```

This behavior reflects the comparison logic of COBOL, MVS Assembler and PL/1 which were the dominant languages on the target platforms when DB2 was originally developed.

Comment: Yes I also thought about this but it take more time to fetch the data, when related records are large.

Comment: This should not take any more time, its an extra comparison on a field you are already checking

Comment: To be precise, DB2 does not _ignore_ trailing spaces; when comparing strings of unequal length it pads the shorter string on the right with spaces to match the longer string's length.